# Nesting drawer navigation within stack navigation

Tags: ios, react-native, react-navigation

I'm struggling with nesting navigation for react-native (iOS). I've read the docs for drawer nav but it is still very confusing..

This is the navigation tree that I'm going for:

```
Landing page 
=> Screen 1
    => DrawerNavigator
        => Screen 2.1
        => Screen 2.2
        => Screen 2.3
        => Screen 2.4
        => Screen 2.5
```

Can you give me a hint on how to implement this? I've gotten the first page to navigate to the second with stack but from there I'm not sure how to set up the drawer navigation.

Thanks a lot!

**My Code so far:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
            import {
                AppRegistry,
                StyleSheet,
                Image,
                View,
                Dimensions,
            } from 'react-native';
            // import SplashScreen from 'react-native-splash-screen'
            import {
                Container,
                Title,
                Content,
                Button,
                Icon,
                Text,
            } from 'native-base'
             import {StackNavigator, DrawerNavigator} from 'react-navigation'

            class MyHomeScreen extends React.Component {
                static navigationOptions = {
                    title: 'Home',
                    headerLeft:
                        <Button transparent >
                            <Icon name='menu'/>
                        </Button>
                }

                render() {
                    return (
                        <Container style={styles.home}>
                            <Content>
                                <Text>It works</Text>
                            </Content>
                        </Container>

                    );
                }
            }
            // class FAQScreen extends React.Component {
            //     render(){
            //         const{navigate} = this.props.navigation
            //         return(
            //
            //         )
            //     }
            // }
            // class AboutScreen extends React.Component {
            //     render(){
            //         const{navigate} = this.props.navigation
            //         return(
            //
            //         )
            //     }
            // }
            // class EventScreen extends React.Component {
            //     render(){
            //         const{navigate} = this.props.navigation
            //         return(
            //
            //         )
            //     }
            // }
            // class ChatScreen extends React.Component {
            //     render(){
            //         const{navigate} = this.props.navigation
            //         return(
            //
            //         )
            //     }
            // }
            // class TrendScreen extends React.Component {
            //     render(){
            //         const{navigate} = this.props.navigation
            //         return(
            //
            //         )
            //     }
            // }
            // class SearchScreen extends React.Component {
            //     render(){
            //         const{navigate} = this.props.navigation
            //         return(
            //
            //         )
            //     }
            // }
            export default class Main extends Component {
                static navigationOptions = {
                    title: 'Career Center',
                }
                render() {
                    const{navigate} = this.props.navigation
                    return (
                        <Container>
                          <Content>
                            <Image source={require('./components/img/bkgrnd.jpg')} blurRadius={2} style={styles.backgroundImage}>
                              <View style={styles.view}>
                                  <Image source={require('./components/img/Asset10.png')} style={styles.photo}/>
                                    <Text style={styles.text}>Welcome to Career Center</Text>
                                    <Text style={styles.text}>
                                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
                                    </Text>
                                  <Button transparent primary style={styles.button} onPress={() => navigate('Home')}><Text>Let's Begin  <Icon name='ios-arrow-dropright-circle'style={{fontSize: 20}}/></Text></Button>
                              </View>
                            </Image>
                          </Content>
                        </Container>
                    )
                }
            }
            const ModalStack = StackNavigator({
                Main: {
                    screen: Main,
                },
                Home:{
                    screen: MyHomeScreen
                },

            });

            // const ModalDrawer = DrawerNavigator({
            //     Home:{
            //         screen: MyHomeScreen
            //     },
            //     FAQ:{
            //         screen: FAQScreen
            //     },
            //     About:{
            //         screen: AboutScreen
            //     },
            //     Event:{
            //         screen: EventScreen
            //     },
            //     Chat:{
            //         screen: ChatScreen
            //     },
            //     Trend:{
            //         screen: TrendScreen
            //     },
            //     Search:{
            //         screen: SearchScreen
            //     }
            // })
            const styles = StyleSheet.create({
                container: {
                    flex: 1,
                    justifyContent: 'center',
                    alignItems: 'center',
                    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
                },
                home:{
                    backgroundColor: 'pink'
                },
                backgroundImage:{
                    flex: 1,
                    resizeMode: 'cover',
                    width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
                    height: Dimensions.get('window').height,
                },
                photo:{
                    width: 200,
                    height: 200,
                    justifyContent:"center",
                    alignSelf:"center",
                },
                text:{
                    paddingTop: 40,
                    paddingLeft:30,
                    paddingRight:30,
                    justifyContent:"center",
                    alignSelf:"center",
                },
                view:{
                    paddingTop:80,
                },
                button:{
                    height:90,
                    justifyContent:"center",
                    alignSelf:"center",
                }
            });


            AppRegistry.registerComponent('gradient', () => ModalStack);
```

Comment: Can we see what you have implemented so far?

Comment: yes. I just added it right now. thank you!

Comment: You can also use drawer component from native base, it is very easy to use .

Comment: There's a drawer comp for native base? Perfect I'll check it out. Thank you!

Comment: Please check these two articles, nesting Drawer navigation has been explained elegantly. These might assist you to resolve the problem:

https://medium.com/@gsveitch/nested-navigators-need-new-i-ndices-f63eeb69c712

https://medium.com/@ivanzotov/react-native-deep-linking-with-authorization-screen-drawer-and-nested-navigators-in-react-4f702b1520a0